# Memory Usage of of external tools in java

Tags: java, memory, runtime.exec

I have a few executable tools. In my Java application I need to launch each of them for a few hundred times and measure their memory consumption based on different inputs. I am using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(externalToolCommand);
```

to execute external tools. But I don't know how to measure the max memory usage of the external tools. 
To make more clear I will exemplify it;
Let say I have prism.exe, mrmc.exe, and plasma.exe which are three executable external tools. I have want to know when I launch one of the tools e.g. prism.exe, how much memory it consumes. I don't need to measure my Java application memory consumption. I need only to know the external memory consumption. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use java or the launching java application to track memory consumption or can you use an external tool?

Comment: On what platform? When you use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` you're outside the JVM.

Comment: I need to use Java to launch  external executables and measure the max memory usage of each tool. @ozborn

Comment: It will run on windows and linux @ElliottFrisch

Comment: I would use an external tool then, there is no point in writing your own code to monitor processes external to the JVM.

Comment: Its executed in a separate process so not seemingly measurable from Java code.

Comment: But the process will be repeated up to a thousand time, which is not feasible to observe manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact code but here is what I could think of. On Windows, you can launch a batch script say **p.bat** from your Java application and launch a powershell script from p.bat say **q.ps1** and now you have got access to  a powershell script. You can run a process monitor tool(I don't know maybe perfmon...) to measure one time memory consumption of it, log it in a text file. Terminate the process from the script. Do the whole process in loop in your Java application. Finally you have got the file containing the process memory consumption n number of times.

But Beware! it is really expensive as it involves File I/O, context switch back and forth, pipelining on the top.

With powershell, the possibilities are endless. But I am no powershell expert so pardon, I can't write the exact code for you. This answer requires a lot of research on your side on various steps involved.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it looks like the only solution I will apply

Comment: @Memin : Indeed it is and this question really needs attention for better answers. No of views are less.

Answer (score -1):

Try "jvisualvm", you can find it at /bin/jvisualvm.exe